# start process so that it can't spawn new ones

Tags: process, sandbox

Is it possible to start new process so that it couldn't spawn new ones (untrusted code)?

Also how do I start a process so it couldn't make any input/output to files and in general any devices?

Comment: It would help answer your question if you gave the OS you need this to work on. In my answer below, three of the four solutions run on only some *ix systems and not others.

Comment: actually not sure about OS, most likely ubuntu server (10.04)

Comment: In that case, of the options I gave, your choices are AppArmor and chroot out of the box. You could probably enable SELinux instead or in addition, but since AppArmor more or less directly competes, I don't think that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a [Mandatory Access Control](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) system like [SELinux](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) or [AppArmor](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/AppArmor).

[This article on SELinux](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/08/21/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-a-new-selinux-policy-module/) will give you some idea of how powerful such systems can be, and the tools you need to develop such policies.

Beware, your wish to restrict access to all files is likely to backfire on you.  In Unix "everything is a file," so entirely preventing all file access will prevent your program from even starting. A more productive approach will likely be to restrict file writing, either entirely or to only a specific directory, and to whitelist categories of files the program can legitimately read.

Another option is to use [chroot](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Chroot) or [jails](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/FreeBSD_jail). With these OS features, instead of preventing file I/O or program execution, you would simply build a restricted environment where there is nothing sensitive for your untrusted program to read, write or execute. Your program could only operate on the files you put into the "box" with it.

Answer (score 1):

If your system uses `pam`, create some dedicated untrusted user, and have a look at `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - an user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
[...]
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
```

You are specifically looking for `nproc` and maybe `nofile`. Though, I doubt any program would work with `user hard nofile 0`. Better adjust the filesystem permissions so that your dedicated user can't access anything you don't want it to access.

Disclaimer: I never used that myself. (I mean the `pam` stuff. Creating a dedicated untrusted user cannot be bad.)

Comment: Also after a bit of looking found this: [setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, ...)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html)

Comment: @ren: yes, I thought there was a shell wrapper for that, but I couldn't find it. Maybe this was available in `ulimit`, but the man page won't tell it anymore.